# Restoring databases using snapshot of one RDS to another existing RDS

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, snapshot

I have 2 RDS which are being used:

1. Production RDS
2. Preprod RDS

I am looking for a way to use the snapshot of the Production RDS and want to restore the data in to the existing Preprod RDS.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can **launch a new database from a snapshot**. So, you could:

- **Create a Snapshot** of the Production database
- **Delete** the Preprod database
- **Launch a new Preprod database** from the Snapshot

The Preprod database would then contain an exact copy of the Snapshot.

It is *not* possible to restore an Amazon RDS Snapshot into an existing database. If you wish to load the data into an existing database, you would need to do this with your own database tools -- AWS does not offer a function to do this for you.

Answer (score 1):

A potential approach for syncing a Preprod RDS instance with production is to use [AWS DMS](https://aws.amazon.com/dms/). Using DMS, you could sync the data into the existing Preprod instance (without deleting that instance and creating a new one). Another potential benefit of DMS is the ability to scrub any sensitive data from the Preprod environment during syncing.  An approach for implementing DMS for this is described [here](https://medium.com/finimize-engineering/securely-syncing-dbs-with-aws-dms-c22f048e9b89).